# svg - style on predefined elements

Tags: css, svg

I try to apply css-style to svg-elements. I want to do this without any script.

While the style seems **not** to work on a `<defs>`:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
    <!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.0//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-SVG-20010904/DTD/svg10.dtd">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    width="300" height="80">

        <style>
            rect:hover {
                opacity: 0.5;
            }
        </style>

        <defs>  
            <rect id="box" x="0" y="0" width="30" height="20" rx="3" ry="3" style="fill:green;stroke-width:1;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)"/>

            <g id="month">
               <!-- first row -->
               <g transform="translate(50 40)">
                    <use xlink:href='#box'/>
                    <text x="5" y="15" fill="grey">Mon</text>
               </g>
               <g transform="translate(80 40)">
                    <use xlink:href='#box'/>
                    <text x="5" y="15" fill="grey">Thu</text>
                </g>
            </g>
        </defs>

            <use xlink:href='#month'/>

        </svg>
```

This works:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
    <!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.0//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-SVG-20010904/DTD/svg10.dtd">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    width="300" height="80">

        <style>
            rect:hover {
                opacity: 0.5;
            }
        </style>

        <rect id="box" x="0" y="0" width="30" height="20" rx="3" ry="3" style="fill:green;stroke-width:1;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)"/>       

    </svg>
```

Is there a way to apply the css? Is there maybe a different way to apply it to a `<defs>`-element? Or any workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT -- This is an answer to the original question which has now been updated and invalidates the response.**

Sure, just give the `use` a class or ID..

```css
.box {
  fill: green;
  stroke-width: 1;
  stroke: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}
.box:hover {
  fill: red;
}
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.0//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-SVG-20010904/DTD/svg10.dtd">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="300" height="80">
  <defs>
    <rect id="box" x="0" y="0" width="30" height="20" rx="3" ry="3" />
  </defs>
  <use xlink:href='#box' class="box" />
</svg>
```

Comment: the problem is that I have multiple `<rect>` in a `<g>`-group inside the `<defs>`, and i want to apply the hover effect individually. (I edited the question to make it more specific)

Comment: No..you can't do that. You can't "reach inside" a `use` to the supposed sub-elements...they're not actually there in the `use`....just referenced like `href`. See the linked question of which yours is a duplicate.